# SQLDependency Caching not working

Tags: asp.net, caching, sqldependency

I am trying to use `SQLDependency Caching` with Query Notifications in my `ASP.NET` application.
I followed [these steps to set up SQLDependency Caching](http://keithelder.net/2009/01/20/sqldependency-and-sql-service-broker-permissions/).I was able to set up the `db` successfully.
However,when I run my application I am getting the following error.

```
Cannot find the specified user 'owner'.
Cannot find the queue
SqlQueryNotificationService-6c3ae823-a678-4ed2-8b97-561b5f2561ee', 
because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
Invalid object name
SqlQueryNotificationService-6c3ae823-a678-4ed2-8b97-561b5f2561ee'.
```

Code **Global.asax**

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDependency.Start(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["McdConn"].ToString());

    }
```

I tried to Google the solution but I could not get any help.

Can anyone help me with this?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you can give the User `sysadmin` rights 
OR

provide `alter` permission to the `dbo` schema.

In order to create a procedure, a function, schema scoped objects etc.., you need at least `ALTER` permission on the target schema. Here is the TSQL syntax,

```
grant alter on schema :: schema_name to  user_name
```

The user should also have the permissions on the Notification Service , Queues.
To grant the permission to user ‘John’ on the `Service` and `queue` use:

```
GRANT SEND on service::SqlQueryNotificationService to John
GRAND RECEIVE on SqlQueryNotificationService_DefaultQueue to John
```

Also the user needs permission to subscribe to notification.( This is done already by you I guess) To do this use:

```
GRANT SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS TO John
```

One last point so far i can guess to help is that in case you have setup `SqlDependency` on a command, then make sure you execute it.Query subscriptions on the server happen only on command execution.

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

This [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dataaccess/archive/2005/09/27/474447.aspx) may prove more helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the help!I altered schema permission and set it to my db user.It did the trick!Thanks

Comment: I don't have any more issues but my cache always is null is it because I am using `SqlDataAdapter`?

Comment: Glad to know its working now. I will also check the same with SqlDataAdapter.

Comment: Thank u for all the help.But My cache is always null.It doesn't give me any exceptions but still it is null always.