# SqlDependency, minimum database permissions, and role-owned schemas

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sqldependency

## Background:

When setting up `SqlDependency` I used information found in these articles in order to give a database user the minimum permissions required:

- [Minimum Database Permissions Required for SqlDependency](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12862/Minimum-Database-Permissions-Required-for-SqlDepen)
- [SqlDependency and SQL Service Broker Permissions](http://keithelder.net/2009/01/20/sqldependency-and-sql-service-broker-permissions/)

and ended up with something like this:

```sql
CREATE ROLE [sql_dependency_user] AUTHORIZATION [dbo];
GRANT REFERENCES ON CONTRACT::[http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/PostQueryNotification] TO [sql_dependency_user];

-- for Start()
GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE to [sql_dependency_user];
GRANT CREATE QUEUE to [sql_dependency_user];
GRANT CREATE SERVICE to [sql_dependency_user];
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO [sql_dependency_user];

-- for subscribe
GRANT SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS TO [sql_dependency_user];
GRANT RECEIVE ON QueryNotificationErrorsQueue TO [sql_dependency_user];
```

## Problem:

If I create a schema owned by this role, and add a user to this role (like in the [keithelder link](http://keithelder.net/2009/01/20/sqldependency-and-sql-service-broker-permissions/) above):

```
CREATE SCHEMA [sql_dependency] AUTHORIZATION [sql_dependency_user]
ALTER USER [user_name] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [sql_dependency]
```

the `SqlDependency.Start()` throws an error:

> Cannot find the specified user 'owner'.
>   Cannot find the queue 'SqlQueryNotificationService-00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
>   Invalid object name 'SqlQueryNotificationService-00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'.

However, if I set the user's `DEFAULT_SCHEMA` to one owned by the user, then it works (of course).

## Questions:

1. Why is there an error when using a schema owned by the role?
2. What options are there if I wanted to avoid creating a schema for each user?

#### Possibly useful info:

- I'm using SQL Server 2012
- I've looked at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480433/sqldependency-caching-not-working), but giving the user `ALTER` and/or `CONTROL` on the schema doesn't seem to work.

Comment: For anyone finding this Q, this DBAs Q may help: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47567/permissions-using-net-sqldependency

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your Q:1)

You need to assign owner to your schema. Run following query and it should fix your problem:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::MyDatabaseName TO NewOwner;
GO
```

In your case:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::[sql_dependency] TO [sql_dependency_user];
```